# How to configure erlang mode in emacs?

Tags: emacs, erlang

OK, I create a .emacs file in the path where I install erlang.

```html
 (setq load-path (cons  "/usr/lib64/erlang/lib/tools-2.7.1/emacs"
      load-path))
      (setq erlang-root-dir "/usr/lib64/erlang")
      (setq exec-path (cons "/usr/lib64/erlang/bin" exec-path))
      (require 'erlang-start)
```

`/usr/lib64` is the folder where I installed erlang. But it doesn't work. On the other hand I use this command:

```
yum install emacs-erlang.
```

Then `/usr/share/emacs/site-emacs/sit-start.d` will have a file named `erlang-init.el`. And the content in this file is:

```html
(setq load-path (cons "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/erlang" load-path))
(setq erlang-root-dir "/usr/lib/erlang")
(setq exec-path (cons "/usr/lib/erlang/bin" exec-path))
(require 'erlang-start)
```

By this way, emacs can work in erlang-mode.
I feel it is strange, because I feel the `erlang-init.el` is wrong but the `.emacs` is right. 
But why in fact `.emacs` can't work rightly?
My OS is fedora 21 and emacs version is 24.4

Answer (score 1):

> OK, I create a .emacs file in the path where I install erlang.

That's not going to do anything unless that path happens to be your `$HOME` directory.

Emacs loads `~/.emacs` -- not *any* file by that name in any arbitrary directory you happen to put it in. (How would Emacs know it was there?!)

The package-managed file is no doubt being loaded because your system's emacs package has configured a `site-start.el` file which loads libraries in `/usr/share/emacs/site-emacs/sit-start.d/`

See: <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs) Init File` <kbd>RET</kbd>